# Each time i'm alt+shift+f my comment fly off in the distance

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, auto-indent, twig-extension

Each time i autoindent (with alt+shift+f) my comments move to the right. Each time i autoindent, they go away more like they still need to be aline.

I'm using VSSCode and it's only when i'm on a twig file with twig comment `{#` (from what i aware of)

Here an exemple:

```
                    </li>
                    {# {% if not is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')   //connexion admin caché
                                                                                                                          <li class="nav-item col-1">
                                                                                                                          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path("app_login")}}">
                                                                                                                          connexion
                                                                                                                          </a>
                                                                                                                          </li>
                                                                                                                          <li class="nav-item col-1">   //pas de pages d'inscription pour mon site.
                                                                                                                          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path("app_register")}}">inscription</a>
                                                                                                                          </li> #}
                    {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

*(i'm french so correct me if i make errors)*

Comment: find the settings of the Twig Formatter, if not found a suitable setting, create an issue at the Twig Language extension

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, thanks, I have Pretty formatter, Twig language and Twig language 2 as formatter. I don't know witch one is really in use. 
I have searched for comments related formatting and found two but they do not solve the issue.

Comment: Also, when you say "create an issue at the twig language extension", so you mean on the gitub (or something) of the extension?

Comment: that means you have 3 formatters active, disable 2 of them. first locate the formatter that is the problem before creating an issue

Answer (score -1):

So i have tested each twig formatter and `Prettier - Code format` is the one working for me for the moment **but i'm not satisfied**: no control over how to format.

I don't know why there are so many twig formatter not working but "meh".